# python flask protect user page

Tags: python, flask

i want to protect page on python-flask, can go on this page only limited users.

I'm write this code :

```
def im_seller():
    if not g.user.seller_fee_paid:
        return redirect(url_for('account.seller_fee'))
    return


@account.route('/account/seller/products.html')
@login_required
@im_seller
def seller_products():
```

the script not working, give this error :

```
TypeError: im_seller() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

where I'm wrong ? thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decorators take a function and need to *return* a function:

```
from functools import wraps

def require_seller(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def require_seller_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if not g.user.seller_fee_paid:
            return redirect(url_for('account.seller_fee'))
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return require_seller_wrapper
```

You will also want to reverse the order of `require_seller` and `login_required` so you can be sure that `g.user` is set:

```
@account.route('/account/seller/products.html')
@require_seller
@login_required
def seller_products():
    return "All the seller's products"
```

See [this answer about decorators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1594484/135978) for all the details as to the whys.

Comment: is safe is this method for protect pages ?

Comment: Its difficult to discuss security concerns without seeing the actual code for `g.user`.

Answer (score 0):

```
from functools import wraps

def require_seller(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def require_seller_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if not g.user.seller_fee_paid:
           return redirect(url_for('account.seller_fee'))
         return f(*args, **kwargs)
 return require_seller_wrapper
```

You should use the python decorator.[Link](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB8QFjAAahUKEwjevNjPp5zJAhXHwo4KHbI-CxY&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsimeonfranklin.com%2Fblog%2F2012%2Fjul%2F1%2Fpython-decorators-in-12-steps%2F&usg=AFQjCNGlnDTD3_ekK9vfZPEly6B4XBB6pw&bvm=bv.107763241,d.c2E)